# Package installation for cairoDevice on Linux

Tags: r, linux, rattle

I am trying to install the rattle package into R, which is running on Linux. The package is working ok so far, except when I start rattle it prompts me to install a package called "cairoDevice". When I attempt this, R gives me the message:

> > package ‘cairoDevice’ is not available for this version of R.
> > A version of this package for your version of R might be available
> > elsewhere

Is there a way to install the cairoDevice package?  I am running R version 4.1.2 on MX Linux 21 which is based on Debian Bullseye.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CairoDevice was removed from Cran around the middle of December. In January, I tried to use Rattle, but it was removed. I had to reinstall everything. I manually installed CairoDevice on R-Studio for Windows, and it worked like a charm. Run the command below in the console (It's the Linux version of CairoDevice package), and it should install the CarioDevice package and let you run Rattle.

```
install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/src/contrib/cairoDevice_2.28.2.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```